# How does light water prevent criticality of natural uranium even as it is outside the zirconium cladding?

Tags: nuclear-physics, material-science, nuclear-engineering

The main reason heavy water is used to allow nuclear reactors to operate with nuclear reactor is that they do not absorb neutrons, allowing an increase in neutron temperature that lets the few U-238 to reach criticality.
However, from the design point of a PWR reactor, this does not make sense to me. The uranium is contained inside ceramic pellets, with the water acting as a coolant and carrying the heat towards the turbine. So even if light water does absorb neutron, wouldn't the uranium within the pellets still reach levels of criticality needed for energy production?

Answer (score 2):

When the fuel is surrounded by water, whether pellets or rods, the neutrons emitted from 1 pellet or 1 rod travel through the water and can hit another pellet or another rod. Light water absorbs neutrons, but more importantly, when neutrons collide with hydrogen, it slows the neutrons down. For nuclear physics reasons, slower neutrons are better at causing chain reactions. When the chain reactions are too fast, the water expands, which increases gaps for neutrons to escape without colliding with the water, so neutrons travel faster again, and the chain reaction rate is lowered. This helps control the rate of reactions.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressurized_water_reactor#Moderator
which is about the role of water in PWR, and
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_cross_section which shows that slower neutrons with lower energy have a higher cross section and probability of causing a chain reaction.

tl;dr neutrons travel through the water between the fuel, and those neutrons are causing chain reactions.

Comment: I was not aware of the relationship between expanding water and the reaction rate, so thank you for that fact. Nonetheless, this does not answer my question

Comment: You're right. To make it more explicitly relevant to your question, my answer explains how light water actually helps uranium reach criticality by making neutrons more likely to react, and helps to maintain stable criticality by its moderating properties. I also clarify that neutrons from 1 pellet travel through the water and cause reactions in other pellets, hence addressing why water has an effect even though it is outside the cladding. If something is still missing, I'll appreciate if you help me understand your exact question.

Comment: I will expand on my question. So, conventional light water pressurized reactors need to use highly enriched uranium as the conventional, (protium) water can parasitically absorb the neutron needed for the reaction, something heavy water reactors avoid. However, if the issue is the water absorbing the neutron between the pellets; why not increase the volume of the pellets themselves? Couldn't that lower the amount of enrichment needed for the uranium, as there are less neutrons escaping for the increased volume-to-surface ratio.

Comment: Critical mass for 15% enriched uranium is over 600 kg. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_mass. Many neutrons will escape a large volume uranium pellet as well, because fast neutrons have a small cross section. Water really helps by slowing the neutrons. It's likely more economical to design a smaller reactor using smaller fuel. And keep in mind that you don't want your fuel to react except when it's in a reactor, so you want the fuel to be very subcritical, and let it be turned on by a neutron moderator.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is not correct.  In a light water reactor, neutrons are generally "born" in the fuel at high energies, leave the fuel rod, slow down in the moderator, and re-enter the fuel at low energies where they fission.  (This is somewhat simplified, see the 4-factor formula for more details).

Criticality is determined by the ratio of neutron production to neutron loss.  This is integrated over the entire reactor (both the fuel and moderator).

In heavy water, there is still some neutron absorption, but much much less than with light water.  Since there is less absorption, you need less production to remain critical, and you can become critical with a lower fuel enrichment.  Heavy water reactors can operate with natural uranium (enriched to about 0.71% U235) but light water reactors need higher enrichment (I'm not sure what the lower limit is, but probably around 2%).

To answer your question directly, light water will decrease the system reactivity because it adds more absorption to the system.